# Best way to remove elements from a container using its ranges version

Tags: c++, range

I face a common problem in my code where I would like to remove only a single element from a reversed std::vector after it satisfies a predicate. I understand there's a number of ways to do this with ranges-v3, but each way I come up with seems a bit convoluted.

Here's an example of the target vector v:

`std::vector v = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 4 };`

The result needs to be vector r:

`std::vector r = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`

Which will be done by removing the first 2 (via a lambda predicate "is_two") that is found when reverse traversing the vector v.

Here's one what it could look like in a vanilla C++ raw loop:

```
auto is_two = [](int a) { return a == 2; };

for (int i = v.size(); --i >= 0;) {

    if (is_two(v[i])) {

        v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's my bad ranges-v3 version:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::view;
namespace ra = ranges::action;

rs::for_each(v | rv::enumerate
               | rv::reverse
               | rv::filter([](auto i_e) { return i_e.second == 2; })
               | rv::take(1),

            [&](auto& i_e) { v.erase(v.begin() + i_e.first); });
```

Ideally I'm wondering if there's some solution that could look something like this:

`ra::remove_if(v | rv::reverse, is_two);`

To generalize, I'd like to know how one can take a container, pipe it through some ranges::view operations, then remove the elements in the resulting range from the original container.

Comment: The key problem is how to convert the iterator on the view to the corresponding iterator of the original container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one seems to have come up with a better approach,
I would like to mention for your benefit the possibility of resorting to good old `reverse_iterator`s.

```
vec.erase(std::prev(ranges::find_if(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend(), is_two).base()));
```

Admittedly, this is not very ranges-ish,
but least it works.

Comment: This is better than my solution in my use case actually, thank you. Could you explain what .base() does ? Thanks again.

Comment: @IanCaburian The [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) on `reverse_iterator` explains this in detail. `base()` returns the underlying iterator which is off by 1 w.r.t. the actual position, hence the `prev`.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of range-based for loops is consistency. Having the same operation executed for each element.

Deleting an element breaks this consistency. So the best solution is a normal for loop where you can use iterators and breaks.

When you have a hammer everything looks like a nail. Don't hammer the ranged loop into a normal one.